# Warning: ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18. Use createRoot instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

***If anyone get this warning it's probably you are using react version > 18.***

**So instead of:**

[image]

**Use:**

[image: React code in version 18]

Comment: You need to add the codes here instead of images.